# Deserialize JSON in Java by inferring/embedding object type

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am serializing a `Map<String, Object>` into JSON using Jackson.

Later when I deserialize it, all objects that are not of primitive type get converted to `LinkedHashMap`'s instead of the class that they originally belonged to.

Is there any way to deserialize JSON into a map so that the nested objects are of correct type?

Comment: http://programmerbruce.blogspot.co.at/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html

Comment: are your POJOs having type references?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'having type references'?

Comment: @D.R. I went through the link, but it seems like none of the solutions apply since the base class is java.lang.Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [constructCollectionType](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html#constructCollectionType(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class)) of [Typefactory](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/TypeFactory.html) with ArrayList as the CollectionClass & your POJO class as the second argument and read the "List" value using ObjectMapper. Like this:

```
List<T> list;
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
TypeFactory t = TypeFactory.defaultInstance();
list = om.readValue(json, t.constructCollectionType(ArrayList.class,POJO_clazz));
```

Hope this helps!